# Can Cassandra be used for creating tables on the fly? If yes, how much time will it take on an average?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, cassandra, nosql

Our customers are allowed to create custom modules(tables) and properties(columns). Currently we are using RDBMS(multi tenant) for handling this usecase and have created a table to store the schema and another table with predefined set of data types in columns(10 columns for each type) to store customer's data.

To improve the performance, I thought about using RDBMS for regular usage and a separate database for storing custom data.

I finalised on Cassandra for its scalability aspects though I'm worried about creating tables on the fly for each customer and automating table tuning to drive better performance.

Answer (score 1):

It's really depends on number of customers, etc. You can of course create new tables by using the driver for particular language.  But every table has some fixed memory overhead, so it's recommended to have max number of tables in low hundreds, something like 200 tables in cluster on average, and not more than 500 tables.  Besides the fixed overhead, you also need to remember that every table has associated memtable that keeps the data.